# Как запустить сервер mongodb через python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

Нужно запустить mongod для дальнейшей работы с БД. Как это сделать командой python? `open()` не помог.
П.С. все почти решилось запуском cmd /K путь к файлу ехе или запуском скрипта ру с командой запуска сервера, но! как открыть это в новом окне консоли???

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос больше вашего кода, `open()` маловато :)

Comment: @gil9red так добавлять нечего, обычно запускаю mongod.exe через консоль, а простой командой open('путь к файлу mongod.exe') yне выходит

Comment: И не выйдет, т.к. это открытие файла в режиме чтения/записи, чтобы считать его содержимое или переписать/добавить. То, что вы хотите, это `system` или `subprocess`. Но проще использовать модуль питона для нужной задачи, попробуйте: pymongo

Answer (score 0):

Для запуска из скрипта можно воспользоваться `os.system` или `os.startfile`:

```
import os
os.system('<путь к файлу mongod.exe>')
os.startfile('<путь к файлу mongod.exe>')
```

Для работы с базой есть модуль [pymongo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver), пример использования из репозитория:

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
>>> db = client.test
>>> db.name
u'test'
>>> db.my_collection
Collection(Database(MongoClient('localhost', 27017), u'test'), u'my_collection')
>>> db.my_collection.insert_one({"x": 10}).inserted_id
ObjectId('4aba15ebe23f6b53b0000000')
>>> db.my_collection.insert_one({"x": 8}).inserted_id
ObjectId('4aba160ee23f6b543e000000')
>>> db.my_collection.insert_one({"x": 11}).inserted_id
ObjectId('4aba160ee23f6b543e000002')
>>> db.my_collection.find_one()
{u'x': 10, u'_id': ObjectId('4aba15ebe23f6b53b0000000')}
>>> for item in db.my_collection.find():
...     print(item["x"])
...
10
8
11
>>> db.my_collection.create_index("x")
u'x_1'
>>> for item in db.my_collection.find().sort("x", pymongo.ASCENDING):
...     print(item["x"])
...
8
10
11
>>> [item["x"] for item in db.my_collection.find().limit(2).skip(1)]
[8, 11]
```

Для установки модуля в консоли использовать команду:

`python -m pip install pymongo`

Comment: Не вижу в вашем коде запуска сервера

Comment: @andreymal, присмотревшийсь, я понял что тоже не вижу... надо бы добавить

Comment: @andreymal да, меня больше интересует запуск сервера, конкретно эту команду я не нашел

Comment: @gil9red os.system('путь к файлу mongod.exe') c этой команды сервер запустился, но скрипт дальше не идет, так как сервер ждет подключение. как вариант- запускать новое окно консоли и в нем файл mongod.exe. Как это прописать командой python? os.system('C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe'...)